# 'Create provisioning profile' button next to 'iOS development' on XCode is not present

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios, provisioning-profile

I am trying to create a free provisioning profile on XCode for an app I am developing using Xamarin. But the Create button next to iOS development is not there:
[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem and here is how I fixed it:

First, Go to: [this xamarin help guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/free-provisioning/)

On there I skipped step 2,3,4 and went straight from 1 to 5.

Finish 5 and 6. Then your General->Signing page will have a status failed message.

Now, to fix that and before you get to step 7 make sure you have 
your device selected at the top [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VR9P7.png)

Then proceed with the instructions on the Xamarin page from step 6 and to the finish, I did not bother going back to step 2,3 or 4, just skip those. Make sure you have the same info in your test app in Xcode as you have in info.plist in the .iOS project in Xamarin.

Now I have my Xamarin Forms app running from Xamarin studio on my device, select (Release | Iphone) and select yourself as a trusted developer in settings on your ios device if you run into that.

Comment: This was the solution for me. Skip 'create iOS Development' (it was already created or is not relevant anymore). Then recreate the provisioning profile in the dummy application in XCode.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already one developer certificate available at developer portal, then you can not create new. You have to revoke old one and then you can create new development certificate.

Open Developer portal and revoke development certificate and try again.

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is to create provisioning in the apple developer account and import/download them in Mac or xcode and use them from there.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html